# Autolayout constraints to change composition on orientation

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout

I'm trying to use auto-layout to achieve the following two layouts. The first is the desired composition in portrait and the second is the desired composition in landscape.

Is this possible with auto-layout and if so what would it look like in terms of constraints?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

Comment: iphone only? ipad only? or both?

Comment: Only on iPad. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set up your constraints in storyboard to get the desired layout for portrait orientation. then add TWO additional constraints and change their priority from 1000 to 999:

1. Bottom Layout Guide.top = RedView.bottom + 10 @999
2. CyanView.leading = RedView.trailing + 10 @999

create `IBOutlet`s for the following constraints:

1. CyanView.top = RedView.bottom + 10 @1000
2. CyanView.leading = leading + 10 @1000

for example:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomSpaceToViewConstraint;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leadingSpaceToSuperviewConstraint;
```

**it is important to switch from `weak` to `strong` references to keep the constraints in memory even when they are not active.**

finally implement the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // check if viewcontroller is opened in landscape
  CGSize size = self.view.bounds.size;
  if (size.width > size.height) {
    // is landscape
    self.bottomSpaceToViewConstraint.active = NO;
    self.leadingSpaceToSuperviewConstraint.active = NO;
  }
}

- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {
  if (size.height > size.width) {
    // will transition to portrait
    self.bottomSpaceToViewConstraint.active = YES;
    self.leadingSpaceToSuperviewConstraint.active = YES;
  } else {
    // will transition to landscape
    self.bottomSpaceToViewConstraint.active = NO;
    self.leadingSpaceToSuperviewConstraint.active = NO;
  }
}
```

feel free to ask if something is unclear!